# How to send HTML message to Python Server using websockets

Tags: python, html, websocket

A program is written to communicate between HTML and Python Server. Connection is established but communication message that I wrote in HTML (is string format) is not getting displayed on server side.

I have tried Python-server programs, websockets and html programming

'''Server side program using python'''

```
 def RcvDatafromUI(self):
        while True:
            json_data = self.conn.recv(1024)
            try:
                if json_data == b'\r\n' or b'':
                    print("Looping Again")
                    continue
                else:
                    print("RcvdDAta : ", json_data)
                    json_string = json_data.decode('utf-8')
                    print("DecodedDAta : ", json_string)
                    #print('type decode=',type(json_string))
                    json_dict = json.loads(ast.literal_eval(json_string))
                    print('json_dict=', json_dict)
                    y = parsejsondata.ParseJson(json_dict)
                    if y == "Success":
                        PloverMain.SendDAtatoUI('{"Command":"Start 
                             ","Status":"Success/Fail"}')
                PloverMain.RcvDatafromUI()
```

'''html code'''

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
   <head>

      <script type = "text/javascript">
         function WebSocketTest() {

            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

               // Let us open a web socket
               var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12345/echo");
               alert("website opened")

               exampleSocket.onopen = function(event) {


                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  exampleSocket.send('{"Command":"Start","Status":"Check"}');
                  alert("Message is sent...");
               };

               exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) { 
                  var received_msg = event.data;
                  alert("Message is received...");
               };

               exampleSocket.onclose = function() { 

                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed..."); 
               };
            } else {

               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }
      </script>

   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "sse">
         <a href = "javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>

Expected:(on server side)
RcvdDAta : '{"Command":"Start","Status":"Check"}'
Acutal:
RcvdDAta :  
b'GET /echo HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:12345\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nOrigin: file://\r\nSec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\nSec-WebSocket-Key: s1qAa96xxm9IZqU21C0TQA==\r\nSec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: Its not HTML code, it’s JavaScript. And a websocket connection works on top of HTTP so the server must implement the connection upgrade of HTTP and then the websocket protocol. It’s not the same as just opening a TCP connection to the server. You need a websocket server library for Python

Comment: Thanks Sami..Got the program.